# Google Cast SDK not working on Xcode 9.4 simulator with wifi but works with ethernet

Tags: ios, xcode, chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to test an iOS app on the Xcode simulator and all networking is fine except for the Google Cast SDK can't find any Chromecasts on my network using wifi. The iMac that Xcode is running on can find the Chromecasts just fine using wifi. The same app on another computer can find them just fine on the simulator also using wifi.

I also tried the Google sample from Github and it can't find any Chromecasts either.

I already added the Simulator app to the firewall exceptions. I also tried it with the firewall off.

What else do I need to do?

Xcode 9.4.1

Thanks.

Comment: If you are still experiencing this issue, you can file a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc

Comment: I did. I'm more curious if anyone else can replicate this on an iMac. Seems to be the only place it happens for me.

Comment: This is now working on my iMac. Not sure if the Mac updated or the cast SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many OSX and Cast SDK updates it now works for me.